# Gravity well and constant total energy in circular orbit

Tags: orbital-motion, potential, potential-energy

According to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206934/total-energy-of-a-circular-orbit), the total energy of an object in a circular orbit in a $1/r^2$ potential does not depend on the radius of the orbit.

However, if you look at "circular orbits" in a gravity well, this is not obvious:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ffI0l8vUK8

In this situation, the particle is constantly losing energy due to friction, but it always stays in a (more or less) circular orbit.

If the total energy of circular orbits stays constant, why does such a particle come closer to the attractor?

Comment: A gravity well is a $1/r$, not a $1/r^2$ potential.

Comment: Are you asking why there is friction in the video, or how eccentric/elliptical orbits of for example planets can exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got your forces and potentials mixed up. If the force is given by:

$$ F(r) = \frac{GMm}{r^n} $$

then the potential is the integral of this:

$$ V(r) = -\frac{GMm}{(n-1)r^{n-1}} $$

In the question you link the force has an inverse cubic dependance, $n=3$, while the gravitational force has an inverse square dependance, $n=2$.

We get a circular orbit when the centripetal acceleration is equal to the gravitational acceleration i.e.

$$ \frac{v^2}{r} = \frac{GM}{r^n} $$

giving:

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r^{n-1}}} $$

So the kinetic energy is:

$$ T = \frac{GMm}{2r^{n-1}} $$

To get the total energy we add the potential energy:

$$ E = \frac{GMm}{2r^{n-1}} - \frac{GMm}{(n-1)r^{n-1}}$$

For the inverse cube force described in the linked question $n = 3$ and we get:

$$ E = \frac{GMm}{2r^{3-1}} - \frac{GMm}{(3-1)r^{3-1}} = 0 $$

so we have the slightly surprising result that the total energy is independent of $r$ and in fact is always zero. For gravity $n=2$ and we get:

$$ E = \frac{GMm}{2r^{2-1}} - \frac{GMm}{(2-1)r^{2-1}} = -\frac{GMm}{2r} $$

so the energy gets lower (more negative) as $r$ decreases. That's why the balls in your video move inwards as they lose energy.

This is an example of the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) that tells us for a potential $V(r) = ar^{-n}$ the kinetic and potential energy are linked by:

$$ 2T = -nV $$

For the cubic force the potential has an inverse square dependance, $n = 2$, so we get:

$$ T = -V $$

and we can see immediately that the sum of the kinetic and potential energy is always zero. For gravity the potential depends on $r^{-1}$ so the virial theorem tells us:

$$ 2T = -V $$

and the sum of the kinetic and potential energy is always $-T$.